# Множественное число

Tags: общие-вопросы

Пожалуйста,подскажите. Предложение: Турнир по борьбе сумо проходил среди юношей 1997-1999 года рождения или 1997-1999 годов рождения

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Помнится, у Розенталя есть правило о тире для обозначения пространственных и временнЫх пределов. Он поясняет это возможностью вставки предлогов "от и до", т.е. в Вашем случае "среди юношей от 1994 до 1997 года рождения"

Comment: Очень благодарна. Все понятно.Спасибо.

Comment: виктор1799: "Помнится, у Розенталя есть правило о тире для обозначения пространственных и временнЫх пределов."===

Пролистал сегодня всего имеющегося у меня Розенталя, такого правила не нашёл.

Comment: В учебнике Д.Розенталя тема - Тире для обозначения пределов пространственных, временных, количественных (сразу после параграфа о тире между подлежащим и сказуемым)

Comment: И какие примеры там приведены? Пока нашёл в розенталевском справочнике по пунктуации в параграфе о соединительном тире только один подходящий к рассматриваемому вопросу пример:

"Крестовые походы XI -- XIII векОВ".

Answer (score 1):

> Пожалуйста,подскажите. Предложение:
>   Турнир по борьбе сумо проходил среди
>   юношей 1997-1999 года рождения или
>   1997-1999 годов рождения.

Верно: *среди юношей 1997-1999 годов рождения*.

Гм... Грамота.ру рекомендует единственное число:

[image]

**Буду думать!**

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: среди юношей 1997-1999 года рождения.  Дело в том, что год один. если написать годов, то получится, что эти юноши родились в 1997годах и в 1999 годах. Получится, что от каждого года существует несколько штук. А смысл: юноши 1997года и 1999года.

Comment: Ну да. В турнире могли участвовать и бороться друг с другом юноши, родившиеся в период с 1.01.1997 г. по 31.12.1999 г.  Организаторов турнира не смущала возможная разница (почти три года) в возрасте  у потенциальных соперников. Ну и как это может говорить о  неправильности выражения "…среди юношей 1997-1999 годов рождения"?

Comment: Здесь, скорее,  имеется в виду не промежуток между этими годами, а именно год рождения этих юношей: 1997 и 1999. Если бы имелся в виду промежуток, то фраза оформлена некорректна. Из этой фразы( с мн.ч.) вряд ли можно понять, что речь идет о именно промежутке. Следует пояснить у автора смысл фразы(и, если имелся в виду промежуток) - исправить предложение.